# What does the rm -rf recur do, when used in a cron?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I have a basic understanding of cron jobs, but I came across a [tutorial](http://www.andrewtheis.net/blog/recurring-invoices-paynow-requirements-and-installation.php) today which recommends adding:

```
30 3 * * * wget http://www.mywebsite.com/bamboodir/index.php/recur
31 3 * * * rm -rf recur
```

What does the `rm -rf recur` do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It compensates for someone who doesn't know about the `-O` option for `wget` -- specifically, `wget -O /dev/null`.

More specifically, the `wget` call in that crontab hits a URL (presumably to trigger some sort of server-side processing -- always a sign of an absolute idiot of a web application or hosting environment).  Since `wget` downloads files, it will store the downloaded file named `recur` it in the current directory.  Then, a minute later, another cronjob deletes the file that was created, for tidiness.

Comment: Actually I believe `-O` to be the incorrect option... Would be `-o` instead

Comment: @Jeremy Bouse: No; `-O` places the document contents somewhere, `-o` places the `wget` console output somewhere.  Using `-o /dev/null` in scripts is possible (although `-q` is better), and `-o /some/log/file` is often useful, but is unrelated to the question.